# Rake task failing to compare current branch to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I am writing a rake task for my rails app to do some stuff after I've determined what the current branch is, but I'm having trouble comparing the current branch to master. My rake task is bellow:

```
desc "TODO"
  task repo: :environment do
  branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
  if branch.eql? "master"
    puts "On master!"
  else
    puts "Not on master!"
  end
end
```

I've checked, and `git rev-parse --abrev-ref HEAD` returns "master". I also double checked that the class of `branch` is `String`. I'm pretty confused why this isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have a command line to test this atm, but are you certain it returns "master" and not "master\n"? Either way, my advice is to study the strings contents more closely.

Comment: That did it..you're the man! thanks!